# Gradle exclude folder from build for specific build type

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-productflavors

I have a folder in my flavor assets that is only needed for the debug builds of flavors

is there a way to exclude this folder from all release builds?

Answer (score 1):

Put the assets in a `debug` sourceset.

Right now, presumably, these assets are in `src/main/assets/` of your module. For those that you only need in `debug`, create `src/debug/assets/`, and move the assets there. They will be included (with your `main` assets) on `debug` builds but will not be included on `release` builds.

Comment: that would work if I didnt have flavors. I have product flavors that each have their own assets, but the assets are only used to debug, the releases would not have those assets. so I cant put the assets globally in the debug/assets directory because in that case I wouldnt be able to use different assets per flavor. so I need to somehow do that exact thing you said in flavors per build type(or the other way around)

Comment: @Mars: "that would work if I didnt have flavors" -- then create build variant sourcesets (e.g., `debugFlavor1`, `debugFlavor2`) and put the assets in there.